# Replace Hyperlink with button in Datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, datagridview, hyperlink

Im able to create a `Hyperlink`  in a `DataGridView` using this;

```
  private void dgvCatalogue_CellContentClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = dgvCatalogue[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 5 && File.Exists(filename))
        {
            Process.Start(filename);
        }

    }
```

Is it possible to replace the `hyperlink` text with an image/button?

Comment: Yes, you would use the [appropriate column type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bxt3k60s(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you certainly can do that.

Here is an example that does it for one Cell only:

```
DataGridViewButtonCell bCell = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
dataGridView1[col, row] = bCell;
```

Now you need to decide what the `Button`'s `Text` should be: It will show the `Value` of the `Cell`. This may be fine, but if your filename includes a lengthy path etc.. you may want to display a shorter text and store the name in the `cell.Tag` instead :

```
string someFileName=  "D:\\temp\\example.txt";

dataGridView1[col, row].Tag = someFileName;
dataGridView1[col, row].Value = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(someFileName);
```

If you want a whole column to display Buttons you can do that like this:

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn bCol = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(bCol);
```

The same cosiderations apply to the cells in the button column.

To test if you are on a button cell you can write:

```
DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
if (cell.OwningColumn.CellType == typeof(DataGridViewButtonCell)) ..
```

To access the values via the `Tag` use code like this:

```
if (cell.Tag != null) string filename = cell.Tag.ToString();
```